# Use two flex directions inside one container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

How can I create the following layout inside **one container**. Is it possible?

I know I can use `display: flex; justify-content: center, align-items:center` to make them all centered, but can I choose to make 2 of the divs into column instead of row?

I want this basically:

[image: https://snag.gy/9Bamrf.jpg]

I'm experimenting with this code.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  height: 600px;
  widows: 700px;
}

.container div {
  float: right;
}

.container div:nth-child(3) {
  flex-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
</section>
```

Comment: you need to wrap 3,4,5 in another flex container to achieve this

Comment: How would that simple solution look if I may ask @Michael_B ? =)

Comment: Im willing to use multiple container as well as Solution, @karthick . I only want the displayed layout :)

Comment: Sure. Im up for anything! :)

Comment: @Michael_B : Grid is an option for me :)

Comment: I have added the solution using another container.

Comment: I also thinking to get more in touch with Grid.. I don't feel Bootstrap 4 even with flexbox ability is looking .. professional.

Comment: Heh, hm . can I add you both as answer? :) That just looks beautiful @karthick . They use a similar layout like this on https://www.hltv.org/matches - but using alot of top : 50px etc. I love how clean that looked :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution using Flexbox with multiple containers

```
<section class="container">
      <div>Item 1</div>
      <div>Item 2</div>
      <div class="flex-col-container">
        <div>Item 3</div>
        <div>Item 4</div>
        <div>Item 5</div>
      </div>
      <div>Item 6</div>
      <div>Item 7</div>
</section>
.container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 600px;
    widows: 700px;
}

.flex-col-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;    
}

.container div {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/j5ur9tw4/

Answer (score 0):

### Flexbox

You can achieve your layout using flexbox and the [**`order`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property.

The default value of `order` is `0` for all flex items. This means their order is determined by their order of appearance in the source code.

By altering the `order` and `flex-basis` values for items 3 and 5, they can be made to appear in the first and last rows, respectively.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  flex: 1;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  order: -1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  order: 1;
  flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
</section>
```

Alternatively, you can use invisible flex items to balance out the empty space. You would need to add 8 items with `visibility: hidden`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  flex-basis: 20%;
}

.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div>Item 1</div>  
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>  
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>
  <div class="hidden">hidden</div>

</section>
```

---

### Grid

**This is the most flexible and robust option.**

With CSS Grid, the layout is relatively simple and easy to build, and there are multiple methods one can use.

In my example below, I've used the ASCII art method of the `grid-template-areas` property.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 50px);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas: " . . . . ." 
                       "  . . three . ."
                       " one two four six seven"
                       " . . five . ."
                       " . . . . ."
}

div:nth-child(1) { grid-area: one; }
div:nth-child(2) { grid-area: two; }
div:nth-child(3) { grid-area: three; }
div:nth-child(4) { grid-area: four; }
div:nth-child(5) { grid-area: five; }
div:nth-child(6) { grid-area: six; }
div:nth-child(7) { grid-area: seven; }

/* non-essential decorative styles */
.container {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
div {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div>Item 1</div>
  <div>Item 2</div>
  <div>Item 3</div>
  <div>Item 4</div>
  <div>Item 5</div>
  <div>Item 6</div>
  <div>Item 7</div>
</section>
```

For a complete explanation of how these Grid properties work, and browser support data, see these posts:

- [grid-template-areas with ASCII art is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)
- [Grid areas not laying out properly in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276)
- [CSS-only masonry layout but with elements ordered horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44377343/3597276)