# Duplicating CSS grid grid-area

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm working on my first site using CSS Grid.

I was wondering whether it is possible to use a CSS Grid Area several times in a layout.

Example:

```
+----------------------------------------+
|                 HEADER                 |
|----------------------------------------|
|                  NAV                   |
|----------------------------------------|
| SIDEBAR   |    CONTENT     | SIDEBAR   |
|           |                |           |
|           |                |           |
|----------------------------------------|
|                FOOTER                  |
+----------------------------------------+
```

My grid element has the following CSS:

```
.grid{
 display:grid;
 grid-area-templates: 
 "header"
 "nav"
 "sidebar"
 "content"
 "sidebar"
 "footer"  
}
```

Is there any way to realise this, or do I have to get around it in some other way, than using pure CSS grid?

Comment: Yes you can apply the "grid" class to multiple elements.

Comment: Thanks. But when I do as in the example above, it only shows the footer. Rest of the grid-areas are placed behind.
Also when checking in dev tools, it shows an error when having duplicate grid-areas in the grid-template-areas

Comment: No...grid areas are specfic, unique and rectangular. It's not clear what you are trying to do. Why do you need the same grid area twice?

Comment: The correct property is `grid-template-areas`...

Comment: ... and, as noted by @Paulie_D, string values must be rectangular... https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276

Comment: Okay. Thought it was clear, that I wanted to use the same content from a specific section twice on the same page, as illustrated in the example.
I'd like to use the sidebar element to put in a Call to Action text and button. Hence the reason for wanting to use the same element several times in the grid

Comment: You can use the same element multiple times in a grid. No problem at all. You just can't do it using the same grid area name in the `grid-template-areas` property. You'll need to use another method. Try grid's **line-based placement**: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276

Comment: Thanks alot @Michael_B