# Is a "complex" matrix style grid powered by a css grid possible?

Tags: html, css, material-ui, css-grid

I am currently trying to achieve the following grid structure in Material-UI with a css grid:

[Desired complex layout](https://ibb.co/yBgyH0G)

I already created a css grid with Material-UI that looks like this:

[Current layout](https://ibb.co/pws5fnx)

This is the code belonging to it:

```
import React from "react";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Container } from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    container: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: "grid",
        gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(6, 56px)",
        gridAutoRows: "56px",
        gridGap: theme.spacing(0.5),
    },
    purple: {
        background: "#e502f9",
        color: "#ffffff",
        height: "100%",
    },
    orange: {
        background: "#f98202",
        color: "#ffffff",
        height: "100%",
        gridColumnStart: "2",
    },
    lightGrey: {
        background: "#d8d8d8",
        height: "100%",
    },
    topLabel: {
        gridColumnStart: "3",
        gridColumnEnd: "span 4",
    },
    sideLabel: {
        gridRowStart: "3",
        gridRowEnd: "span 4",
        writingMode: "vertical-rl",
        transform: "rotate(180deg)",
    },
    align: {
        alignItems: "center",
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        textAlign: "center",
    },
}));

function ExamplePage() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Container component="main" maxWidth="xs">
            <div className={classes.container}>
                <div />
                <div className={clsx(classes.topLabel, classes.align)}>
                    Text x-axis
                </div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.sideLabel, classes.align)}>
                    Text y-axis
                </div>

                <div />
                <div />
                <div className={clsx(classes.purple, classes.align)}>1</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.purple, classes.align)}>2</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.purple, classes.align)}>3</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.purple, classes.align)}>4</div>

                <div className={clsx(classes.orange, classes.align)}>A</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>4</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>4</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>4</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>4</div>

                <div className={clsx(classes.orange, classes.align)}>B</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>3</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>3</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>3</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>3</div>

                <div className={clsx(classes.orange, classes.align)}>C</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>2</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>2</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>2</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>2</div>

                <div className={clsx(classes.orange, classes.align)}>D</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>1</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>1</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>1</div>
                <div className={clsx(classes.lightGrey, classes.align)}>1</div>
            </div>
        </Container>
    );
}

export default ExamplePage;
```

Does anybody also has an idea on how to programatically set the blue dot somewhere in the grid? I am not sure if this is possible at all in a css grid?

Comment: With currently available CSS Grid technology, grid areas must be rectangular. [Tetris-shaped grid areas are not possible.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Michael_B stated, grid areas must be rectangular. Therefore, it's not possible to create a more complex layout.