# Why are CSS named grid areas not in quotes?

Tags: css, language-lawyer, css-grid, specifications, w3c

According to the spec, [the value for `grid-area` is `grid-line`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#propdef-grid-area), which [further uses `custom-ident`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#typedef-grid-row-start-grid-line). Then [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/custom-ident) states that identifies cannot be put between quotes, which will make it a string value, which by itself is reasonable.

But adding these all up, [named grid areas](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-grid/#common-uses-named-areas) must be accessed via an ID without quotes. See the comparison in the example below:

```css
.grid {
    display:grid;
    grid: "a b" 1fr "c d" 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
}

.foo {
/* this works just fine, putting it to area b in upper right corner */
    grid-area: b;
}

.bar {
/* quoting the area name fails to resolve correctly */
    grid-area: "c";
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <span class="foo">foo</span>
    <span class="bar">bar</span>
    <span class="hello">hello</span>
</div>
```

This seems very counter-intuitive. When one creates grid area names using something like `grid: "area1 area2" / 1fr 1fr;`, the names are in quotes, feeling like values. But somehow they become identifiers, like variable names. Why this design choice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The CSS Grid spec developers decided to use *identifiers* instead of *strings*, when defining named grid areas with the `grid-area` property, **for the sake of consistency with the rest of CSS**.

The vast majority of CSS properties use identifiers, not strings, for their values. (Notable exceptions to this rule include `font-family`, `content` and `grid-template-areas`, which use both.)

From a 2013 discussion between spec writers:

> **8. Named Lines Syntax**
>
> The previous named lines syntax was pretty awkward...
>   It also used strings as CSS-internal identifiers, which we don't do
>   anywhere else. Tab and I took the proposal from that thread, which was
>   to switch to identifiers and use parentheses to group multiple names
>   for the same position. This has the benefit of
>
> - Using identifiers, consistent with the rest of CSS
> - Providing visual grouping of names that identify the same location
> - Allowing the named grid areas template syntax (which uses strings) to co-exist with named lines in the grid-template shorthand.
>
> We think this is a dramatic improvement over the previous syntax, and
>   hope that the rest of the WG agrees. :)
>
> *source: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Aug/0353.html*

There's also this thread:

> Looking over the current syntax for declaring named grid lines in
>   grid-definition-rows/columns, we've come to the conclusion that the
>   current syntax is *terrible*:
>
> - We're using strings to represent a user-ident, which is inconsistent with everything else in CSS.
>
> Our current suggestion for fixing this is to switch the line names to
>   idents...
>
> *source: https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2013Mar/0256.html*

---

### More details

In CSS Grid, [named grid areas](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#grid-template-areas-property) can be defined using the `grid-area` property, and then referenced in the `grid-template-areas` property.

Here's an example:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: "   logo    nav     nav   "
                         " content content content "
                         " footer  footer   footer " ;
}

.logo  { grid-area: logo;    }
nav    { grid-area: nav;     }
main   { grid-area: content; }
footer { grid-area: footer;  }
```

Another example, using the shorthand `grid` property on the container, comes from the question:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid: "a b" 1fr "c d" 1fr / 1fr 1fr;
}

.foo {
    grid-area: b;
}
```

In this case, the `grid` property breaks down to this:

```
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-areas: "a b"
                     "c d";
```

So it's clear that named grid areas, when referenced in `grid-template-areas`, are **strings**, but when they're defined in `grid-area`, they are **identifiers** (`<custom-ident>`).

What's the difference?

According to the [CSS Values and Units Module](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/) specification:

> [§ 4.2. Author-defined Identifiers: the `<custom-ident>`
>   type](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#custom-idents)
>
> Some properties accept arbitrary author-defined identifiers as a
>   component value. This generic data type is denoted by
>   `<custom-ident>`, and represents any valid CSS identifier that would
>   not be misinterpreted as a pre-defined keyword in that property’s
>   value definition. Such identifiers are fully case-sensitive (meaning
>   they’re compared by codepoint), even in the ASCII range (e.g. example
>   and EXAMPLE are two different, unrelated user-defined identifiers).

What are CSS identifiers?

As defined in [section 4 of the same spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#textual-values), they are *"...a sequence of characters conforming to the `<ident-token>` grammar. Identifiers cannot be quoted; otherwise they would be interpreted as strings. CSS properties accept two classes of identifiers: pre-defined keywords and author-defined identifiers."*

---

> [§ 4.3. Quoted Strings: the `<string>`
>   type](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-4/#strings)
>
> Strings are denoted by `<string>` and consist of a sequence of
>   characters delimited by double quotes or single quotes. They
>   correspond to the `<string-token>` production in the CSS Syntax
>   Module.

---

So why pick an identifier instead of a string as the value in the `grid-area` property?

As noted in the first part of the answer, there is no stated technical reason for using one over the other. The decision came down to uniformity: identifiers represent the vast majority of values in CSS, so `grid-area` values would do the same to maintain consistency.

Comment: Very nice answer; just a minor nitpick: you write "CSS property values use identifiers, not strings. (Notable exceptions to this rule include `font-family`" but `font-family` definitely uses identifiers! It has keywords such as `sans-serif`, `monospace` etc, which cannot be put in quotes. Only the variable font names should be.

Comment: IMO the rule is to always use identifier and only rely on string when there is ambiguity and especially space involved. `grid-area` accept only one area so we are safe as we won't have any space unlike `grid-template-areas` where the use of space can represent either a separation between two area or the separation between two rows. I guess without String, it would probably be difficult to find an *easy* syntax for  `grid-template-areas`. Maybe the real question is: why `grid-template-areas` uses string (this sounds more counter-intuitive than the other).

Comment: Correct. But `font-family` also uses strings, such as "Times New Roman", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Comic Sans MS", "Arial Black" and so on. My point was that strings were accepted values. I didn't mean to imply they were exclusive.  @MrLister

Comment: Both other properties (`content` and `grid-template-areas`) also accept strings and identifiers as values.

Comment: I modified that paragraph to be more clear. Thanks for the feedback.