# grid template areas failing to place grid items

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to wrap my head around css grids, but in this code the grid template areas are not functioning as i would expect them to. I need my WinLoseDisplay to span 2 columns, but it just takes up one column and instead of having my page grid look like this:

```
" b d d"
" b b b"
" b b b"
```

It looks like this

```
" b d b"
" b b b"
" b b  "
```

Any help would be much appreciated

```css
.MainContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 200px 200px 200px;
  grid-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-areas: "b d d" "b b b" "b b b"
}

.ButtonRock {
  grid-template: "b";
}

.WinLoseDisplay {
  grid-template: "d";
}

.ButtonPaper {
  grid-template: "b";
}

.PlayerSelection {
  grid-template: "b";
}

.PcSelection {
  grid-template: "b";
}

.ButtonScissors {
  grid-template: "b";
}

.ButtonPlay {
  grid-template: "b";
}

.Placeholder {
  grid-template: "b";
}
```

```html
<div class='MainContainer'>
  <div class='ButtonRock a'>
    <button id='Rock'>Rock</button>
  </div>
  <div class='WinLoseDisplay'>
    winlosedisplay
  </div>
  <div class='ButtonPaper a'>
    <button id='Paper'>Paper</button>
  </div>
  <div class='PlayerSelection a'>
    player selection
  </div>
  <div class='PcSelection a'>
    pc selection
  </div>
  <div class='ButtonScissors a'>
    <button id='Scissors'>Scissors</button>
  </div>
  <div class='ButtonPlay a'>
    <button id='Play'>Play</button>
  </div>
  <div class='Placeholder a'>
    placeholder
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using the wrong property on the grid items.

Don't use `grid-template`. Use `grid-area`.

---

The [`grid-template`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grid-shorthand) property applies to *containers*. It's a shorthand for:

- `grid-template-columns`
- `grid-template-rows`
- `grid-tempate-areas`

So your grid item rules—such as `grid-template: "b"`—breaks down to this:

- `grid-template-rows: auto`
- `grid-template-columns: none`
- `grid-template-areas: "b"`

These rules don't apply to grid items. They only work on a grid containers.

Instead, use `grid-area: b`. ([Note that the values are not in quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60026586/why-are-css-named-grid-areas-not-in-quotes).)

Then, makes sure that each grid item has a unique `grid-area` name, so they can each be individually placed in the `grid-template-areas` rule.

Related (but not duplicates):

- [Why aren't my grid-template-areas with ASCII art not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)
- [Grid areas not laying out properly in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276)