# Multi to single column grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a grid and I wish to place items in two columns like so:

```
card | side
card
card
etc..
```

But at certain screen sizes, I wish to slot in the side element into the cards like this:

```
card
card
side
card
card
etc..
```

I've tried this for the first layout:

```
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
            "card side"
            "card side"
            "card side";
    grid-template-columns: 2.2fr 1fr;
}

.card {
    grid-area: card;
}

.side {
    grid-area: side;
}
```

This works, but when I want the single column I use:

```
 .grid {
    grid-template-areas:
            "card"
            "card"
            "side"
            "card"
            "card";
}
```

But the above does not work - the browser won't recognize it.

Comment: [Grid areas must be a single filled-in rectangle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276).

Comment: As of today, grid areas need to be contiguous. Maybe in the future with CSS regions, this might be doable, but right now, you need to sequence your elements.