# I want to design a layout with CSS grid by creating a grid area, but layout does not work as required

Tags: html, css, layout, responsive-design, css-grid

I am learning to design a layout with CSS grid.

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/nileshyav-the-decoder/pen/BarOgGE?editors=1100) link of my code.

And here is a [layout image on Github](https://github.com/nileshyav/cssGrid-project/blob/master/img/layout.jpeg).

I want to insert one more row with three columns above the footer with this CSS code which is responsible for the layout:

```
grid-template-areas:
    "nav nav nav"
    "sidebar mycover mycover"
    "sidebar main content1"
    /* "main main main" */    // I don't know why this does not work
    "footer footer footer";
```

When the new fourth row code `"main main main"` is commented out, the layout works fine like the image link I gave above. But when I uncomment `"main main main"`, the layout crashes and nothing is displayed. What is the problem?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #1eaafc;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 130deg, #6c52d9 0%, #1eaafc 85%, #3edfd7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* border: 6px solid #171717; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.cover {
  grid-area: mycover;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content1 {
  grid-area: content1;
}

.content2 {
  grid-area: main;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 1fr 100px 80px;
  grid-template-areas: "nav nav nav" "sidebar mycover mycover" "sidebar main content1"
  /* "main main main" */
  "footer footer footer";
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item nav">nav</div>
  <div class="item cover">cover</div>
  <div class="item sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="item content1">content1</div>
  <div class="item content2">main</div>
  <div class="item footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `grid area` must be a square or a rectangle, **3 x 1** or **2 x 2** or **4 x 2** or **1 x 1**, for example. Non-rectangular shapes are not allowed. I added a `content2` grid area and a `lowercover` grid area to your layout to try to demonstrate this more clearly.

Your `main` grid area covered just one column and one row, namely the third row. So trying to put three `main` grid areas covering three columns in the fourth row is not possible.

I created a new class, `orange`, by copying `background-color` and `background-image` from your `item` class and swapping the values of the `red` and `blue` components (i.e. `#1eaafc` became `#fcaa1e`). I applied this `orange` class to `main`, `lowercover`, and `content2` and now the `orange` areas of the `grid` is what you were trying to achieve with your original code.

If you want to create a non-rectangular shape on a grid then you need to think about putting another `grid` or `flexbox` within your `grid`. But this may become difficult to manage for multiple different device screen sizes.

The following answer about [grid-template-areas not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459717/why-arent-my-grid-template-areas-with-ascii-art-not-working/45461670#45461670) explains this very well too.

Here is a link to a [complete guide to CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.item {
  background-color: #1eaafc;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 130deg, #6c52d9 0%, #1eaafc 85%, #3edfd7 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #171717;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.cover {
  grid-area: mycover;
}

.sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.lowercover {
  grid-area: lowercover;
}

.content1 {
  grid-area: content1;
}

.content2 {
  grid-area: content2;
}

.footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

.main {
  grid-area: main;
}

.container {
  border: 5px solid red;
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 1fr 1fr 80px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "nav nav nav"
    "sidebar mycover mycover" 
    "sidebar main content1" 
    "lowercover lowercover content2"
    "footer footer footer";
}

.orange {
  background-color: #fcaa1e;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 130deg, #d9526c 0%, #fcaa1e 85%, #d7df3e 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item nav">nav</div>
  <div class="item cover">cover</div>
  <div class="item sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="item lowercover orange">lower cover</div>
  <div class="item main orange">main</div>
  <div class="item content1">content1</div>
  <div class="item content2 orange">content2</div>
  <div class="item footer">footer</div>
</div>
```