# grid-template-areas doesn't take all columns for one div

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am building a page with grid.

And I am in a stuck with `grid-template-areas`.

I want that `.cinema` takes all space (2 column) and `.why` only first column.

But when I wrote `.cinema` twice, Chrome showed the `grid-template-areas`  - "invalid property value"

Why does it happen?

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  grid-template-areas: "cinema" "why"
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "cinema cinema" "why"
  }
}

.cinema {
  grid-area: cinema;
  background: url(comigo/other/homepage-featured-new-1920x745.jpg) no repeat;
  background-position: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
}

.why {
  grid-area: why;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cinema">
    <h3>Comigo OTT/STB solutions - redefine TV experience</h3>
    <p>
      <form>
        <button>OUR SOLUTIONS</button>
      </form>
  </div>

  <div class="why">
    <h2> WHY COMIGO?</h2>
    <h4>Comigo redefines the TV experience
      <p>
        <form>
          <button>CONTACT US</button>
        </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appear to be numerous problems in your code.

First, you have `form` elements contained inside `p` elements. This is invalid HTML.

A paragraph element can contain only *phrasing content*. See [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9852312/3597276) and the [**spec**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

Second, the string values of the `grid-template-areas` property must have the same number of columns. In your media query, the first row has two columns, and the second row has one column.

```
grid-template-areas: "cinema cinema" "why"
```

This is invalid CSS. The rule is ignored.

Try this instead:

```
grid-template-areas: "cinema cinema" "why ."
```

A period (`.`), or a sequence of contiguous periods (`...`), can be used to represent an empty grid area and maintain equal columns among strings.

See here for more details:

- [Grid areas not laying out properly in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276)
- [grid-template-areas with ASCII art is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)

Comment: Thank you, Michael_B. I didn't put a dot. It was a problem. It is my first step with grid and I don't know all rules yet. You help me!