# CSS Grids not working on actual mobile devices despite displaying perfectly on all screen sizes during testing

Tags: html, css, mobile, browser, css-grid

I am new to CSS Grids (and web development in general) and have recently started using CSS Grids, which I find great except for one big problem: none of it seems to work on any mobile devices despite:

1. having tried various mobile browsers including Firefox, Chrome, Samsung browser, Safari, UC browser and Baidu browser
2. updating all browsers to latest versions
3. testing display at all screen sizes by manually reducing size of browser in Firefox and Chrome on PC (displays perfectly at all sizes when testing in this way!)
4. testing mobile version using Firefox's built-in mobile screen test feature (also displays perfectly when testing in this way!)
5. tried testing on various mobile device models at http://responsivedesignchecker.com/ (all display almost exactly as intended!).

Here is the HTML (please forgive any obvious errors as I am a novice)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Grid</title>
<meta charset="UTF8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
<div class="grid">

<menu>
<div>Home</div>
<div>News</div>
<div>Whitepaper</div>
<div>About</div>
</menu>

<!--HEADER-->
<header>
<h1 class="site-title">Silubium</h1><br>
<span class="motto">The currency of the future</span>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="buttons">
<img src="images/buttonAndroid.png">
<img src="images/buttonIOS.png">
<img src="images/buttonWindows.png">
<img src="images/buttonLinux.png">
</div>
</header>

<!--CONTENT-->
<intro>
<div class="introText">
<h1 class="contentHeader">Silubium: a currency built for the future</h1>
<p>Silubium is the world's first 4th-generation cryptocurrency and has been designed from the outset to be a consumer currency. Silubium enjoys the advantages of high-level government support for the "one road, one belt" economic development strategy of China and is already being actively implemented by several large enterprises Hong Kong, Macao and elsewhere.
<a href="#">Read More<a>.</p>
</div>
<div class="iframe"><iframe src="iframe.html" height="200" width="400"></iframe></div>


</intro>

<whySilubium>
<h1>Why Silubium?</h1>
<div class="icons">
<div class="icon"><img src="images/icon_1.png"><p class="iconCaption">Designed for the consumer</p></div>
<div class="icon"><img src="images/icon_2.png"><p class="iconCaption">Cutting-edge 4th-generation<br> public ledger</p></div>
<div class="icon"><img src="images/icon_3.png"><p class="iconCaption">Unmatched security features</p></div>
<div class="icon"><img src="images/icon_4.png"><p class="iconCaption">24/7/365 support</p></div>
<div class="icon"><img src="images/icon_5.png"><p class="iconCaption">Designed for stability</p></div>
<div class="icon"><img src="images/icon_6.png"><p class="iconCaption">Globally accepted</p></div>
</div>
</whySilubium>

<!--FOOTER-->
<footer>
<div class="contact">
<div class="footerTitle">Contact Ryker Freegeld</div>
<div class="footerItem">Email: rygeld@silubium.com</div> 
<div class="footerItem">Twitter: @Silubium</div>
<div class="footerItem">Youtube: "Silubium" (channel)</div>
</div>
<div class="links">
<div class="footerTitle">Related Links</div>
<div class="footerItem"><a href="djw.top">Silktrader Trading platform</a></div>
<div class="footerItem"><a href="www.silubium.org">www.silubium.org</a> (Chinese promotional site)</div>
</div>
</footer>

<!--COPYRIGHT-->
<div class="copyright">
<div class="copyrightText">Design and coding by <a style="color:white" href="#">Ryker Freegeld</a></div>
</div>

</body>
</div>
</html>
```

And here is the CSS using CSS Grids code:

```
/*
THEME: SILUBIUM GRID
AUTHOR: DON HARTIG
VERSION: 1.0
*/

body {background-color:#404040;
    font-family:arial;}

menu {height:20px;
display:grid;
grid-template-columns:70% 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
justify-items:end;
}

/*HEADER*/  
header {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:header;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
    grid-template-rows:auto;
    justify-items:center;
    color: white;
    background-color:#404040;
    background-image:url("images/blueSGbackground.png");
    width:100%;
    height: 720px;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:100px;}
.site-title {padding-top:150px; font-size:50px;}
.motto {    font-size:20px;}     
.buttons {
    text-align:center;
    }

/*CONTENT*/
.contentHeader {
    color:white;
    display:grid;
    justify-items:left;
    font-size:40px;
    }
intro {
    display:grid;
    grid-area:content;
    color:white;
    background-color:#404040;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
    grid-template-rows:2fr;
    justify-items:;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    }
whySilubium {display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
    justify-items:center;
    color:white;
    padding-top:30px;}
.icons {display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
    justify-items:center;
    }
.iconCaption {text-align:center; margin-top:0px;}
.icon > img {padding:40px 40px 5px 40px;}   
.iframe {display:grid;
    justify-items:center;}

/*FOOTER*/
footer {
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr;
    grid-template-rows:auto;
    grid-area:footer;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    justify-items:center;
    font-size:14px;
    padding:30px;
    }
.footerTitle {display:grid;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    padding-bottom:20px;}
.footerItems {}

.grid {
    grid-template-areas:
    ". header ."
    "h1"
    "content"
    "footer footer footer"
    }

/*COPYRIGHT*/
.copyright {
    height:50px;
    background-color:blue;}
.copyrightText {display:grid;
    justify-items:center;
    color:lime;
    padding-top:6px;}

/*RESPONSIVE*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    header {padding-bottom:;}}  
    footer {grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    intro {grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;}
    .icons {grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;}}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
    .icons {grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr 1fr;
            grid-column-gap:200px;}}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
    intro {padding-left:40px;}
    .icons {grid-column-gap:300px;}}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1500px) {
    header {padding-top:70px;}
    .site-title {padding-top:50px;}
    .motto {padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px;}}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am struggling to get this working under a deadline.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why your code works in any browser. Your `grid-template-areas` rule is invalid. All string values must have the same number of columns. In your code (`.grid`), you have "3", "1", "1", "3". https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276

Comment: Thanks Michael. Your comment was extremely useful and believe it or not, even though fixing the grid-areas problem did not solve the problem completely, it is the only thing that made any difference at all and from there I eventually managed to get more or less what I wanted as a basic layout (although strangely some of the changes still don't update in actual mobile devices). You helped me solve a huge problem and I wish I could give you more than just one point. If you have a Silubium wallet, I can send you some coins though (www.silubium.com) :).

Comment: You're welcome. Upvoting my answers that are useful to you is enough. Thanks anyway for the coin offer.

Comment: Cool, thanks again. :)

Comment: Grids are not supported in mobile browsers. FYR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=txZq7Laz7_4