# CSS grid not working for me

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am having issue with `display: grid`. I want header top and 33% width sidebar column and 66% for content. And I have declared `grid-area`. Can you help me?

```css
.head {
  grid-area: head;
  background: tomato;
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  background: purple;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: orange;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "head head head"
    "side" "content content"
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box head">
  </div>
  <div class="box side">
  </div>
  <div class="box content">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The accepted answer hits the nail on the head. But also note that  `"head head head"  "side" "content content"` is invalid code. String values for `grid-template-areas` must all have an equal number of columns, or the rule is ignored. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276

Comment: Ok noted.. Thanks Mate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just move the content next to the sidebar

```css
.head {
  grid-area: head;
  background: tomato;
}

.side {
  grid-area: side;
  background: purple;
}

.content {
  grid-area: content;
  background: orange;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "head head head"
    "side content content"
}

.box {
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box head">
  </div>
  <div class="box side">
  </div>
  <div class="box content">
  </div>
</div>
```