# Re-ordering grid items

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I have task to do in GRID css (the task main goal is to do this in GRID, not flex etc). I have two columns in my GRID, every column has own divs, but it is not important, because I already did everything. Important thing is to make RWD. In the RWD I need combina both columns to one (already did) and reverse them. 
How to reverse column B with all divs to be at the top of new column??

[image: How to reverse column B with all divs to be at the top of new column??]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  float: left;
  width: 49%;
}

.column {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">A1</div>
  <div class="column">A2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">B1</div>
  <div class="column">B2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please look at guide [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Simple and easy. But we need to see the code you have tried.

Comment: ok i added some code, what I want to do here is, when screen comes to 600px width, row with B1 and B2 go on the top, A1 and A2 on the bottom.

Comment: You are talking about grid, but you use float ?

Comment: its only for example. im just wondering how to put B columns on the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `grid-template-areas` and a media query to make it work.

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/14omd02t/6/)

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: " a1 b1 " 
                       " a2 b2 ";
}

@media ( max-width: 500px) {
  .row { grid-template-areas: " b1" "b2" "a1" "a2" ;}
}

.row> :nth-child(1) { grid-area: a1; }
.row> :nth-child(2) { grid-area: a2; }
.row> :nth-child(3) { grid-area: b1; }
.row> :nth-child(4) { grid-area: b2; }

/* just decorative styles */
.row {
  grid-gap: 5px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}
.column {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">A1</div>
  <div class="column">A2</div>
  <div class="column">B1</div>
  <div class="column">B2</div>
</div>
```

These posts will help you understand how `grid-template-areas` works:

- [grid-template-areas with ASCII art is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)
- [Grid areas not laying out properly in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276)