# Using repeat in grid-template-areas instead of having to repeat grid cell names

Tags: html, css, css-grid

When using grid-template-areas in CSS grid, I wanted to have a header spanning the full width. Yes I can define the template-grid-columns with repeat( 12, 1fr) but what I was looking for is a way to use it instead of having to write the name of the column 12 times. See below.

```
grid-template-areas: 
            "article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero"
            "header header header header header header header header header header header header"
            "main main main main main main main main main aside aside aside"
            "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
```

The first row that has 'article-hero written twelve times, is there a way to use repeat so that I can do `repeat(12,article-hero)` instead of writing it out 12 times?

Comment: You can do it using grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the response. I need it to have the repeat also hold the name of the cell. Eg. I want to know if there is a short hand to repeat adding article-hero to all 12 cells so that I can then say #article-hero { grid-area: article-hero; }

Comment: yes, You can do it using this, grid-template-areas: "article-hero"; grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);

Comment: Will give it a go. Would be great if I can get it sorted.

Answer (score 4):

When you are using [**`grid-template-areas`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Grid_Template_Areas) you have to take the trouble to write the *grid areas* out - you don't have *repeat* here (Its actually very similar to [**`ASCII art`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art)).

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero article-hero"
      "header header header header header header header header header header header header" 
      "main main main main main main main main main aside aside aside"
      "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer";
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper>* {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
}

article {
  grid-area: article-hero;
}

header {
  grid-area: header;
}

main {
  grid-area: main;
}

footer {
  grid-area: footer;
}

aside {
  grid-area: aside;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article>hero</article>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```

A few things to note when using `grid-template-areas`:

1. They should be *rectangular* - see an example [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45459717/grid-template-areas-with-ascii-art-is-not-working).
2. The number of columns must be equal in each string of your `grid-template-areas` property - else they would be invalid - see an example [**`here`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45647833/grid-areas-not-laying-out-properly-in-css-grid).

---

**Position Items Using Grid Lines**

You can switch to [**`line-based-placements`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Line-based_Placement_with_CSS_Grid) here with a 12-column grid (using `grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr)`) and using `grid-column` property - see demo below:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper>* {
  border: 1px solid cadetblue;
  grid-column: span 12;
}
.wrapper main {
  grid-column: span 9;
}
.wrapper aside {
  grid-column: span 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <article>hero</article>
  <header>header</header>
  <main>main</main>
  <aside>aside</aside>
  <footer>footer</footer>
</div>
```