# Make grid area span two rows, but not two columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I've been trying to create a layout that looks like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  grid-template-areas: "main aside"
                       "main main";
}

.wrapper > aside {
 grid-area: aside;
}

.wrapper > main {
  grid-area: main;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <main>MAIN</main>
</section>
```

Comment: You can fake such a shape with the float properties and draw somehow, borders via box-shadow . here is an old pen of mine https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HKEpo and a variant, https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/jmsoB *(not the best design ;) )*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not really an answer but for the fun and to remenber & to show that the behavior of floatting elements can be used to fake such a shaped layout.

`Float` is not obsolete and can once be still usefull even if `display` has become very good. 
so here is from my comment and [an old pen](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/HKEpo) an example looking close to your grid.

It is about  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context

> A **block formatting context** is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a Web page. It is the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs and in which floats interact with other elements.

demo below

```css
/* my grid not flexible enough ...

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  grid-template-areas: "main aside"
                       "main main";
}

.wrapper > aside {
 grid-area: aside;
}

.wrapper > main {
  grid-area: main;
}

*/
/* back to the past */
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;/* to keep float inside */
}

.wrapper aside {
  float: right;
  width: 300px;
}


/*makup*/
.wrapper {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px inset red;
}
.wrapper aside {
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px white, 0 0 0 6px red;
  margin: 0 0 1.5em 1em;
}

main {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <main>MAIN</main>
</section>
```

to let content of `main` flow under `aside`, remember that you are dealing with `float`, do not reset display or oveflow to main to keep it this way , read about block formatting context.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the main problem:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  grid-template-areas: "main aside"  <--- problem
                       "main main";  <--- problem
}
```

You can only set rectangular grid areas with `grid-template-areas`.

Tetris-like shapes are invalid (at least in the current version of CSS Grid, which is [Level 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/)).

However, maybe you can use Grid's [line-based placement](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#line-placement) technique to achieve your layout:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 300px;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
}

.wrapper > aside {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}

.wrapper > main {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <aside>Aside</aside>
  <main>MAIN</main>
</section>
```

More details:

- [grid-template-areas with ASCII art is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45459717/3597276)
- [Grid areas not laying out properly in CSS Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45647833/3597276)